# Custom query Custom-Post-Types creates error

Tags: query

I created a custom-post-type for members of a firm. On the start-page I tried to call them via custom query but it shows an error. Heres my code: http://pastebin.com/rRzNcqPP and the error says: Call to a member function get_queried_object() on a non-object in /www/htdocs/w00e3b6a/hosting/basecamp/wp-includes/query.php on line 43

What did I wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
 query_posts('post_type=team-member&posts_per_page=2&paged=$paged');
```

instead of

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => 'team-member',
                    'posts_per_page' => 2,
                    'paged'=>$paged
                    ) );
```

and then the while loop as

```
if(have_posts()) while(have_posts()) : the_post();
```

instead of

```
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```